# Add white space after each xml element usinh php

Tags: php, xml

I have created a xml from an array using php.The result is listed below.

```
<Mst><Mstrow><sCode>10</sCode>Test<sName></sName></Mstrow></Mst>

But I want to show this xml with white spaces between each element lik this

 <Mst> <Mstrow> <sCode>10</sCode> <sName>Test</sName> </Mstrow> </Mst>
```

Below is my code ,

```
 $results = Array ( [0] => Array ( [sCode] => 10 [sName] => Test) ) ;
 $main = $dom->appendChild($dom->createElement('Mst')); 
 if($results != Array()){
    foreach ($results as $datas) {
        $row ->$main->appendChild($dom->createElement('Mstrow'));
            foreach ($datas as $name => $value) {
                    $row
                        ->appendChild($dom->createElement($name))
                        ->appendChild($dom->createTextNode($value));
                    }
                }
            }
```

Please provide a solution

Comment: `I have created a xml from an array using php`-> show us the code how's you created.Change in code will give you expected outcome what you want. But at-least show us the code so that we can check

Answer (score 0):

I may have missunderstood the qn, and I assume in your (pre) example test should be between `<sName>` tags. I would have thought a simple string replace before you echo/save your XML string would do the trick?

e.g.

`echo str_replace( '><' , '> <', $myXml->asXML());`